Why default User still creating even added the EnableWebSecurity annotation and InMemoryUserDetailsManager
I am trying to make an application that uses custom User and Admin credentials for Authentication. However, the custom user credential gets an unauthorized exception. Only I can log in using the system-generated credentials user and generated password.
SecurityConfig.java
     import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;

     @Configuration
     @EnableWebSecurity
     public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin(withDefaults())
                .httpBasic(withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsService() {
        System.out.println("--------------------------------In UserDetailsService");
        UserDetails user = User.withUsername("user")
                .password("{noop}password")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

        UserDetails admin = User.withUsername("admin")
                .password("{noop}password")
                .roles("USER", "ADMIN")
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user, admin);
    }}

ApiGatewayApplication,java
@SpringBootApplication
public class ApiGatewayApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ApiGatewayApplication.class, args);
}
}

application.properties
spring.application.name=ApiGateway
server.port=8083
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=QuestionService
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://QuestionService
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/question/**

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].id=QuizService
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].uri=lb://QuizService
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates[0]=Path=/quiz/**, /quiz-test/**

pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.gateway</groupId>
    <artifactId>ApiGateway</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ApiGateway</name>
    <description>This is a API Gateway Server</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>23</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

API Gateway log
2024-10-10T15:00:11.167-04:00  INFO 21580 --- [ApiGateway] [           main] ctiveUserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration : 

Using generated security password: da26512d-fcb0-49c0-a8e3-5814686ed7a5



that means that your security config is not found, you have to place it in either the same directory or in a subdirectory of where the main function is

Hi @Toerktumlare, the Security Configuration is in the same directory. We can see that the log is printing from the security configuration.
Screenshot added in post.

Please do not post images of code, i will not click that link.

After rigorous testing and research, I found out where is the problem:
The problem is that when spring boot application is enabled with spring-cloud-starter-gateway and spring-boot-starter-security, then the application is trying to use ReactiveUserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration class from security.reactive package present in the spring-boot-autoconfigure library to configure reactive based user details service to do the authentication.
That means that your application is enabled with Spring WebFlux by default when spring-cloud-starter-gateway is used and it has to use that auto-configuration class which is specially made to configure and used to authenticate webflux based application.

Let me demonstrate what I mean:
Scenario 1: When I remove spring-cloud-starter-gateway & jakarta.servlet-api dependencies and added the spring-boot-starter-web dependency, then your configuration works. You can test it out. I was able to login via both user and admin. Note: This detail is added just to prove that your configuration is correct.
Scenario 2: I took the same configuration and dependencies as it is that you have provided, then the error that I faced.
org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Invalid Credentials
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractUserDetailsReactiveAuthenticationManager.lambda$authenticate$1(AbstractUserDetailsReactiveAuthenticationManager.java:108) ~[spring-security-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:45) ~[reactor-core-3.6.10.jar:3.6.10]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4576) ~[reactor-core-3.6.10.jar:3.6.10]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.6.10.jar:3.6.10]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:166) ~[reactor-core-3.6.10.jar:3.6.10]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.run(MonoPublishOn.java:182) ~[reactor-core-3.6.10.jar:3.6.10]
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68) ~[reactor-core-3.6.10.jar:3.6.10]
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28) ~[reactor-core-3.6.10.jar:3.6.10]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]

2024-10-13T12:30:27.577+05:30 DEBUG 6790 --- [so-security-demo] [oundedElastic-2] o.s.s.w.s.DefaultServerRedirectStrategy  : Redirecting to '/login?error'

Screenshot:

See the log above, it's using flux libraries behind the scenes. This means that your application is enabled with flux when spring-cloud-starter-gateway and spring-boot-starter-security library is used.
How to fix this:
Update SecurityConfig to this:
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.ReactiveAuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.EnableWebFluxSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.MapReactiveUserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain;

import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;

@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeExchange(requests -> requests.anyExchange().authenticated())
                .authenticationManager(reactiveAuthenticationManager())
                .formLogin(withDefaults())
                .httpBasic(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ReactiveAuthenticationManager reactiveAuthenticationManager() {
        System.out.println("--------------------------------In UserDetailsService");
        UserDetails user = User.withUsername("user")
                .password("{noop}password")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

        UserDetails admin = User.withUsername("admin")
                .password("{noop}password")
                .roles("USER", "ADMIN")
                .build();
        return new UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager(new MapReactiveUserDetailsService(user, admin));
    }
}

Points to be noted:

SecurityWebFilterChain needs to be used for web-flux support. SecurityFilterChain won't work.

You have to use the ReactiveAuthenticationManager and also MapReactiveUserDetailsService designed for reactive based in-memory user details.


Then it will work.
Logs:
2024-10-13T12:40:05.073+05:30 DEBUG 6981 --- [so-security-demo] [ctor-http-nio-2] a.DelegatingReactiveAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on '/' using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedReactiveAuthorizationManager@70d82571
2024-10-13T12:40:05.073+05:30 DEBUG 6981 --- [so-security-demo] [ctor-http-nio-2] ebSessionServerSecurityContextRepository : Found SecurityContext 'SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=user, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, CredentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]]]' in WebSession: 'org.springframework.web.server.session.InMemoryWebSessionStore$InMemoryWebSession@4d1672fd'
2024-10-13T12:40:05.074+05:30 DEBUG 6981 --- [so-security-demo] [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.s.w.s.a.AuthorizationWebFilter       : Authorization successful

Also, your system generated password thing will be solved as well. It won't generate at all.
See if this helps.
